# Is it possible to do like element.sendKeys(name-*.zip), say name-Ian.zip? Or any equivalents?

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

I am trying to use sendKeys in the following format:
element.sendKeys(path+ file), where file is like name-*.zip, e.g. name-Ian.zip.

Is it possible or any equivalent option is available? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean like uploading any file starting with `name-` and ending with `.zip`, without knowing the whole file name?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through the files in the directory, select the first file that matches your naming pattern and send the path of the file as parameter for the `sendKeys` method.

Here's an example of a method that would return the path of the filtered file:

```
public String getFilteredFilePath(String directoryPath) {
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);

    File[] filteredFiles = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.startsWith("name-") && name.endsWith(".zip"));

    return filteredFiles != null && filteredFiles.length > 0 ? filteredFiles[0].getAbsolutePath() : null;
}
```

You can then use this file path as parameter for `sendKeys`.

I've used lambda expressions and ternary operator, in case they look strange and you want to research them...